# Dynamic SQLite queries

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to implement dynamic queries in my Android app, to let the users search according to some criteria. In this case I'm trying to search simply by an integer value. Here's my attempt:

```
...
public String[][] listarNegocio(int idProyecto,
    int minimo,
    int maximo)

{
    String[][] arrayDatos = null;

    String[] parametros = {String.valueOf(idProyecto)};

    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor = querySQL("SELECT *" +
        " FROM negocio" +
        " WHERE ? in (0, id_proyecto)", parametros);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        int i = minimo - 1;
        arrayDatos = new String[maximo - minimo + 1][20];

        while(cursor.moveToNext() && i < maximo)
        {
            // Here I fill the array with data

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    CloseDB();
    return(arrayDatos);
}

public Cursor querySQL(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    Cursor oRet = null;
    // Opens the database object in "write" mode.
    db = oDB.getReadableDatabase();
    oRet = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    return(oRet);
}

...
```

I tested this query using SQLFiddle, and it should return only the rows where the column `id_proyecto` equals the parameter idProyecto, or every row if idProyecto equals 0. But it doesn't return anything. If I remove the WHERE clause and replace "parametros" with "null", it works fine.

Additionally, I need to search by text values, using LIKE. For example, `WHERE col_name LIKE strName + '%' OR strName = ''`. How should I format my parameters and the query to make it work?

Comment: Don't use raw queries, use query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)

Comment: @barq Can you explain us **why**?

Comment: Easier to parameterize the query than dealing with strings. Also better practice, since it prevents injections and other bugs.

Comment: @barq Completely **false**. You can use the same **?** parameters for preventing SQL injection and (at least for me) it's easier to deal with SQL, directly.

Comment: @DerGolem It's meant as a shorter form of `WHERE (FieldName = ? OR ? = 0)` If ? = 0, it should return every row.

Comment: Sure, you -can- make it safe, but by using a queryBuilder you can be sure it is safe.

Comment: @DerGolem `id_proyecto` is the column name.

Comment: @DerGolem I know. But it wouldn't work that way because the column `id_proyecto` in my table can never be 0. That would make the 0 in `IN (0, ?)` pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do one query for each case. For an id that exists, do `SELECT * FROM negocio WHERE id_proyecto = ?`. For an id that doesn't exist (I'm assuming 0 isn't a real id), just query everything with `SELECT * FROM negocio`.

Code should be something like this:

```
if(parametros[0] != 0){
    cursor = querySQL("SELECT *" +
        " FROM negocio" +
        " WHERE id_proyecto = ?", parametros);
} else {
    cursor = querySQL("SELECT *" +
        " FROM negocio", null);
}
```

Regarding your second question, it depends on what you're looking for, you could use `LIKE '%param%'` or `CONTAINS` for occurrences in between text, `LIKE param` for partial matches or just `= param` if you're looking an exact match.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work. Regarding the `LIKE` part, I was unsure of where I had to place the `%`; now I see it has to go inside the `parametros` array.