# How to Ignore or Replace a Row if some columns are the same?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this `ID|MONTH|YEAR|AMOUNT|PAID|ISPAID|INDEX_ID` where `INDEX_ID` is an auto filled integer acting as PK and AI and `PAID|ISPAID` are auto filled with 0.0

The Problem I have is when I fill a transaction with the same `ID|MONTH|YEAR|AMOUNT` I would like to either replace or ignore it. Preferably ignore it. But I would still like to know both.

Is there a way to do this in sqlite3?

this is my current SQL String:

```
SQLStr := "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ClientRecord(id, month, year, amount) 
            VALUES(" ir.ID "," ir.MONTH "," ir.YEAR "," ir.AMOUNT ");"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the duplicate insertion through use of `NOT EXISTS` within your INSERT query string :

```
SQLStr := "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ClientRecord( id, month, year, amount)
SELECT " ir.ID "," ir.MONTH "," ir.YEAR "," ir.AMOUNT "
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM ClientRecord 
                     WHERE id     = " ir.ID " 
                       AND month  = " ir.MONTH "
                       AND year   = " ir.YEAR "
                       AND amount = " ir.AMOUNT ");"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b1e1ccd53c396c8df61db5570efb9f5e)</kbd>

***As a side note** : Prefer rewriting the above query by using dynamic query logic by replacing those variables by question marks rather than variable concatenetion in order to make the query more secure against injection*

Comment: do you have an example of dybamic query logic?

Comment: @fenchai maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566981/dynamic-sqlite-queries)